# Problema enrutamiento para acceder al controlador

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola soy novato en Rails y tengo problemas para acceder desde una vista a un método del controlador.

he creado un formulario en la vista

```
  <form id="form-cargaMasiva" action="/redmine/issues/load" method="get">
...
...
...
</form>
```

mi objetivo es que cuando hago el submit mediante javascript me lleve al método del controlador que he llamado load, mi controlador se llama issues_controller, según tengo entendido para que te redirija al método load hay que poner en el fichero routes.rb

```
get 'issues/load', :to => 'issues#load'
```

Pero no hay manera de que funcione, me da un 404

Comment: 404 es fallo en la conexion con el servidor. la url está bien ?

Comment: No lo sé, estoy más perdido que un mono en una feria, estoy modificando una aplicación rails libre que se llama redmine, y claro al añadir un formulario no se como hacer que me redirija al método del controlador que he creado

Comment: @lois6b en realidad un error 404 es que no se ha encontrado el recurso pero hay conexión con el servidor

Comment: Si pruebas a ejecutar en la terminal 'rake routes' te mostrará los recursos que están definidos en la aplicación. Si no está definido el endpoint que necesitas, prueba a definirlo en el archivo routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- En tu action apuntas a `/redmine/issues/load`, pero en tu routes tienes definido `issues/load`. Para que funcione, deben ser ambas rutas iguales.
- Si estás aprendiendo rails, atente a las convenciones rails. Estás usando un verbo `GET` para un formulario lo cual, a pesar de que debería funcionar, está mal. Normalmente deberías usar un `POST` para crear elementos  y un `PUT` o `PATCH` para actualizar elementos.
- Estás usando `<form>` cuando lo que deberías hacer es usar `form_for` o por último `form_tag`.
- Deberías ponerle un alias a tu get, que quede algo como `get 'issues/load', :to => 'issues#load', as: cualquier_nombre`, entonces después llamarlo como `cualquier_nombre_path` donde lo necesites.

No se si estés aprendiendo de algún tutorial o que, pero si todas esas cosas que detallé en lo poco de código que mostraste son por algún tutorial que estabas siguiendo, mejor cambia de tutorial.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por las indicaciones, me han servido de mucho.